# Passing multiple email addresses to a single array in templateRoles

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to pass a list of comma-separated email addresses to the email element in templateRoles, i.e., "email" => $to, where $to is a comma-separated list of emails? Or does each recipient have to be specified individually in its own array?

Answer (score 0):

Each recipient has to be specified in their own array.  The DocuSign platform identifies recipients by a combination of their *name*, *email*, *recipientId* (and if using [Embedding Feature](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) the *clientUserId* as well).  So you can't just have a comma-separated list stemming off of the email property of a given recipient.

For example, using a JSON formatted request body your recipients should typically look something like this:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "firstemail@gmail.com",
            "name": "First Recipient",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "100",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "email": "secondemail@gmail.com",
            "name": "Second Recipient",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "tabs": {
                "initialHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "200",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "200",
                        "yPosition": "200",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "carbonCopies": [
        {
            "email": "thirdemail@gmail.com",
            "name": "Third Recipient",
            "recipientId": "3",
            "routingOrder": "3"
        },
        {
            "email": "forthemail@gmail.com",
            "name": "Forth Email",
            "recipientId": "4",
            "routingOrder": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above JSON would add 4 recipients to a given envelope- 2 signing recipients (one with 1 signHere tab and the other with a signHere tab and an initialHere tab) and 2 carbon copy (CC) recipients.